# Can I re-dial a Twilio Call using call SID, Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twilio

I'm trying to make a function for re-dialing a Twilio Call everytime I get a "failed" status.

Can I use Call SID or other data to make a re-dialing function?
Instead of using the same method as making the first call like:

```
call = client.account.calls.create({ 
:url => xxxxxxxxxx, :to => to_no, 
:from => from_no, 
:method => "GET", 
:if_machine => "Hangup",
:timeout => "60"
})
```

Since, I can get the call.sid
and call status via: call_status = client.account.calls.get(call.sid)

Thank you!

Comment: What have _you_ tried so far?

Comment: Not, yet implemented. I still thinking about the best way to make it. Rather than using the same method as the first call like:

  call = client.account.calls.create({
                        :url => xxxxxxxxxx,
                        :to => to_no, 
                        :from => from_no,
                        :method => "GET",
                        :if_machine => "Hangup",
                        :timeout => "60"
                })

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack overflow. here we expect you to have a go at writing it yourself, then show us the code you have so we can help you. (edit your question and put it there, don't put it in comments because the formatting is awful). We won't write or design your code for you. So, have a bash. then show us where you get to.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The way to make calls using the REST API is the method you show in your question already. There's no way, that I know of, to create a call out of an old Call SID. Each call you make will have a new SID as that is the unique identifier for objects within our system.

Are you looking for some other functionality here?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for another way to call again. But if it's the function mentioned above is the best way to make a re-dial call, I have no choice but to duplicate the same code and pass the parameters again.

Comment: Rather than duplicate the code, it might be better to encapsulate the call you want to make and the arguments that don't change (for example `method`, `ifMachine`, `timeout`) allowing you just to pass the arguments that do change (for example `to`). I think it would be confusing for the API to provide more than one way to make a phone call.